Firefox and Chrome printing to PDF with A4 size
I have some issue with printing this following page.
I tried to print this web page to PDF without any special driver just using native Print/SaveToPDF function in Firefox and Chrome browsers.
The issue is that I always get A3 landscape (297x420 mm)
I would ask some folks to check what is done with this web page and how I can ensure that generated PDF with Print/SaveToPDF give me A4 portrait (210x297 mm) instead A3 landscape (297x420 mm), of course using native print/save to PDF function in Firefox and Chrome browsers.

It's because this CSS file on the page defines the following:
@page {
  size: a3;
}

Normally you can pick the size of the document in More settings like on this website, but when page size is strictly defined, the default Chrome/Firefox PDF printer implementation skips the choice.
Either:

use a PDF printer with more freedom, like from Foxit
disable/override that CSS, which may prove cumbersome as @page doesn't seem to be listed even when emulating print
emulate screen in Chrome DevTools (F12) -> kebab menu icon  -> More tools -> Rendering -> Emulate CSS media type and then print


Finally I use: @page {size: a4;  !important;} with https://add0n.com/stylus.html and this works fine
